# Cómo insertar un string largo en pequeños chunks de 20 caracteres en sql-server 2016?

Tags: sql

Tengo un store procedure que recibe como parametro un string.
Pongamoslo facil, una tabla con 3 campos: (ID, MiSTRINGLargo, otra cosa)

mi campo que recibe el string tiene un limite de caracteres pongamosle... un varchar(20).

(NO QUIERO HACER SPLIT), Cómo puedo recortar el string de a 20 caracteres hasta guardar todo el string en varios rows?

Ejemplo:

string 'sopas'en:

```
1, 'so' ,etc
1, 'pa' ,etc
1, 's', etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ir haciendo

`SUBSTRING(@variable_entrada, <caracter_inicial>, <longitud_campo>)`

E ir aumentando `<caracter_inicial>` en un ciclo.

Answer (score 2):

Esto se puede resolver muy fácilmente con una tabla de números (*tally table* en inglés). Una tabla de números es una tabla con una columna llena de números consecutivos, usualmente empieza en 1 o 0. Podemos hacer una tabla al vuelo que requiere cero lecturas usando un código como el siguiente.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

De ahí, solo tenemos que modificar un poco para limitar la cantidad de filas que requerimos y generar los segmentos que se insertarán.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000) = 'Tengo un store procedure que recibe como parametro un string. Pongamoslo facil, una tabla con 3 campos: (ID, MiSTRINGLargo, otra cosa)',
        @longitud int;

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT 0 -- Fila para iniciar en cero
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (LEN( @String) / @longitud) --Obtener los números necesarios para la cadena
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n 
    FROM E4
)
SELECT  n + 1 AS orden, --Para poder definir como estaba ordenada la cadena
        SUBSTRING( @String, 1 + (@longitud*n), @longitud) AS valor --El valor por segmento. Lo único variable por fila es el segundo parámetro que indica la posición de inicio
FROM cteTally;
```

Por último, podemos convertir este código en una función para que no se tenga que escribir todo cada vez que haga falta.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SegmentarCadena(
    @String varchar(8000),
    @longitud int
)
RETURNS TABLE --Regresará una tabla
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- Previene table spools innecesarios en UPDATES puesto que no hace referencia a ninguna tabla
AS
RETURN
    WITH 
    E(n) AS(
        SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n) --10 filas
    ),
    E2(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    ),
    E4(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas. Suficientes para varchar(8000)
    ),
    cteTally(n) AS(
        SELECT 0 -- Fila para iniciar en cero
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (LEN( @String) / @longitud) --Obtener los números necesarios para la cadena
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n 
        FROM E4
    )
    SELECT  n + 1 AS orden, --Para poder definir como estaba ordenada la cadena
            SUBSTRING( @String, 1 + (@longitud*n), @longitud) AS valor --El valor por segmento. Lo único variable por fila es el segundo parámetro que indica la posición de inicio
    FROM cteTally;
```

Al final, tu insert queda como

```
INSERT INTO MiTabla(
    ID,
    MiSTRINGLargo, 
    OtraCosa
)
SELECT  @ID,
        sc.valor,
        @AlgunOtroValor
FROM dbo.SegmentarCadena( @MiStringLargo, 20) sc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!,

i solved it like this:

```
DECLARE @variable_entrada varchar(MAX) = '123456789',
@chunk varchar(4) = 0,
@positionStart int = 1,
@positionEnd int = 4

--0 a --7999 son mis 8000
--PRINT LEN(@variable_entrada)
while(LEN(@variable_entrada) > 3)
BEGIN
    
    --lo que inserto
    SET @chunk = SUBSTRING(@variable_entrada, @positionStart, @positionEnd) --ojo no es inclusive
    PRINT @chunk --123 , --678

    --PRINT @positionStart
    SET @positionStart = @positionStart + 4
    --PRINT @positionStart

    SET @variable_entrada = SUBSTRING(@variable_entrada, @positionStart, LEN(@variable_entrada)) 
    --PRINT @variable_entrada --6789

    SET @positionStart = @positionStart - 4
END
if(LEN(@variable_entrada) > 0 )
PRINT @variable_entrada
```

Comment: Español, por favor. Y recuerda que en un rato puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises  mi respuesta. No solo será más rápida, también funciona para insertar datos sin necesidad de utilizar instrucciones fuera de SQL Server.